# Analyzing questionnaire data with control group

Tags: r, distributions, survey

I have 12 questions weighted on a 5-point Likert scale.
20 people responded to each question, so we have 20 rows and 12 columns, with each cell ranging from 1 to 5. Questions 1-4 measure a random variable R1, 5-8 measure R2, and 9-12 measure variable R3. Finally, these 20 people come from 4 different areas, A,B,C and D. So I want to use respondents from A as some control group, then see how different the other groups responded.

So my question is; should I use a regression analysis or is there a better option? I am doing the analysis with R

Comment: if you have latent variables than structural equation modelling will let you handle both the measurement and structural model in one analysis, it can be implemented with the lavaan package in R.

Comment: Thank you for your advice @ChrisNovak. I will take a look at the package